# Flask application - how to get checkbox status?

Tags: python, dataframe, flask

I'm trying to learn flask with small app for saving data from Pandas DataFrame into json file - and I have problem with this save part... I tried many approaches, but can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
After application starts, I want to set checkbox values, and after click Save button, save this information in json source file - but I can't figure out how to do it :/
This is my Python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime, date
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
import os
from textwrap import dedent
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import BooleanField

contests_list = []

def save_changes():
    global df
    df['participate'] = df['participate'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)
    df['award'] = df['award'].replace({r'<[^>]+>': ''}, regex=True)
    df['how_to_participate'] = df['how_to_participate'].replace({r'<[^>]+>': ''}, regex=True)
    df['link'] = df['link'].replace({r'<a[^>]+href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>': r'\1'}, regex=True)
    df['rules'] = df['rules'].replace({r'<a[^>]+href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>': r'\1'}, regex=True)
    df['picture'] = df['picture'].replace({r'<img[^>]+src="([^"]+)"[^>]*>.*?<\/a>': r'\1'}, regex=True)
    df['valid_until'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid_until']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    df.to_json("contests_list.json", orient='records')
    return redirect('/table')
    

df = pd.read_json("contests_list.json")

df['link'] = df['link'].apply(lambda x: f'<a href="{x}">Link</a>')
df['rules'] = df['rules'].apply(lambda x: f'<a href="{x}">Regulamin</a>')
df['award'] = df['award'].apply(lambda x: f'<p> {x.replace("new_line", "<br>")}</p>')
df['how_to_participate'] = df['how_to_participate'].apply(lambda x: f'<p> {x.replace("new_line", "<br>")}</p>')
df['picture'] = df['picture'].apply(lambda x: f'<img src="{x}" width="300" height="250"></a>')
df['participate'] = df['participate'].apply(lambda x: f'<input type="checkbox" checked>' if x == 1 else f'<input type="checkbox">')
df['valid_until'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid_until']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


def format_color_groups(df):
    today = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    formatted_df = df.copy()
    formatted_df['valid_until'] = pd.to_datetime(formatted_df['valid_until'])
    formatted_df['valid_until'] = formatted_df['valid_until'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    formatted_df['valid_until'] = pd.to_datetime(formatted_df['valid_until'])

    def get_color(row):
        #todo
        return ''
    return formatted_df.style.applymap(get_color, subset=['valid_until'])


def startWebApp():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    @app.route('/table')
    def table():
        formatted_df = df.sort_values(by='valid_until').style.background_gradient()
        return render_template('consets.html', tables=[formatted_df.to_html()], titles=[''])
   
    @app.route('/save', methods=['POST'])
    def save():
        save_changes()
        return redirect('/table')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host="localhost", port=int("5000"))

startWebApp()
```

Next, my html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contests</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contests</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/save">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
        {{ tables[0]|safe }}
        <br>
        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And source file with sample data:

```
[
    {
        "award": " award 1",
        "how_to_participate": " x",
        "link": "http:127.0.0.1",
        "picture": "<img src=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"250\"><\/a>",
        "rules": "<a href=\"\">reg<\/a>",
        "source": "home",
        "title": "title1",
        "valid_until": "2022-09-29",
        "participate": 0
    },
    {
        "award": " award2",
        "how_to_participate": " x2",
        "link": "http:127.0.0.1",
        "picture": "<img src=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"250\"><\/a>",
        "rules": "<a href=\"\">reg<\/a>",
        "source": "home",
        "title": "title2",
        "valid_until": "2022-10-02",
        "participate": 0
    },
    {
        "award": " award3",
        "how_to_participate": " x21",
        "link": "http:127.0.0.1",
        "picture": "<img src=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"250\"><\/a>",
        "rules": "<a href=\"\">reg<\/a>",
        "source": "home",
        "title": "title3",
        "valid_until": "2022-11-01",
        "participate": 0
    },
    {
        "award": " award4",
        "how_to_participate": " x3",
        "link": "http:127.0.0.1",
        "picture": "<img src=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"250\"><\/a>",
        "rules": "<a href=\"\">reg<\/a>",
        "source": "home",
        "title": "title4",
        "valid_until": "2022-10-27",
        "participate": 0
    },
    {
        "award": " award5",
        "how_to_participate": " x4",
        "link": "http:127.0.0.1",
        "picture": "<img src=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"250\"><\/a>",
        "rules": "<a href=\"\">reg<\/a>",
        "source": "home",
        "title": "title5",
        "valid_until": "2022-10-06",
        "participate": 0
    }
]
```

This is my latest version. Before I was trying for example something like this:

```
def save_changes():
    global df
    checkbox_values = request.form.getlist('participate')
    print(checkbox_values)
    df['participate'].apply(lambda x: print(x))
    #df['participate'] = df['participate'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == '<input type="checkbox" checked>' else 0)
    def extract_checkbox_status(html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        input_tag = soup.find('input')
        if input_tag and input_tag.has_attr('checked'):
            print(1)
            return 1
        print(0)
        return 0
        

    df['participate'] = df['participate'].apply(extract_checkbox_status)
    df['award'] = df['award'].replace({r'<[^>]+>': ''}, regex=True)
    df['how_to_participate'] = df['how_to_participate'].replace({r'<[^>]+>': ''}, regex=True)
    df['link'] = df['link'].replace({r'<a[^>]+href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>': r'\1'}, regex=True)
    df['rules'] = df['rules'].replace({r'<a[^>]+href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>': r'\1'}, regex=True)
    df['picture'] = df['picture'].replace({r'<img[^>]+src="([^"]+)"[^>]*>.*?<\/a>': r'\1'}, regex=True)
    df['valid_until'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid_until']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    #df['participate'] = df['participate'].apply(lambda x: True if x == '<input type="checkbox" checked>' else False)
    #df['participate'] = df['participate'].astype(int) 
    df.to_json("contests_list.json", orient='records')
    return redirect('/table')
```

But in this case 'print(checkbox_values)' was always return start values of checkbox, no metter how I check them :(
Any tips how to achive my goal...?